# Why are some Shared Web Hosting configuration changes delayed?

Tags: shared-hosting, configuration, 1and1

I have used several shared web hosting packages over the years, however, more recently I have encountered *issues* that have me questioning the purpose of delays in configuration changes.

The web host in question is [1&1](http://www.1and1.com/), which applies config changes with a delay.

**The question** // *What* is the benefit of delaying configuration changes?

**Update** additional question // Why would some changes take the specified time (*e.g. 10 minutes*), and sometimes several hours?

---

**The story** // The most recent incident was caused using the 1&1's WebsiteBuilder by a tech to create a temporary page. After this, the finalized site (html/js/css/etc.) was placed on the server through FTP. The following events occurred after:

1. Removed the domain from the *selection* was applied immediately (*i.e. selected -none-*).
2. Changed the domain destination folder, which were delayed a few minutes.

   - Skip a few hours
3. Another tech *attempted* some changes through the WebsiteBuilder.

   - This change forced the Control Panel to copy the existing site files to a different folder.
   - The change was applied immediately.
4. My **mistake** here was removing the newly created folder, and reapplying the domain destination folder.

   - This change did **not** take effect immediately; in fact, it took *several hours*.
   - The last tech kept attempting to *fix* the site by making changes on the Control Panel.

Due to the configuration effect delays on step 4, the tech kept making changes (*presumably adding more changes to the configuration queue, I'm guessing*).

Finally, all of these changes threw the site into a cycle of failed access, directory listing denied, 404's, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer: Lowering load to HDD hosting system or sometimes to CPU.

Why: It depends on scripts which rules the whole process. It may be cron scripts which runs every 5-10 min or scripts run when system idle or ...

This situation similar to github pages - all changes visible with delay up to 10 minutes. This time set on nginx config file as cache time

For sure ask you hoster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added an additional question - why are the changes sometimes the specified estimated time, however, sometimes the very same changes take hours?

Comment: @Jesse As I say I can just conjecture. It may depend on server's load level so you changes wait until webserver process all clients requests and then apply you changes.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer! If you can think of anything else, please add as a comment and/or update the answer. I will wait a day or two to see if the question gains more traction; if not, I will accept your answer.